# Stop printing org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy errors

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

In my mule flow, I get org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy error printed to log when the message is rejected. I have an exception strategy that can handle the exception, but the error and exception stack trace is printed to the log which will make the log unreadable by time. How can it be stopped? Actually, it is funny to have an error message when something is rejected by a filter, it should just silently work on accepted items.

```
ERROR 2017-07-10 11:33:18,723 [[...-flow].connector.sftp.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using a newer mule version the catch exception strategy should allow you to set `logException="true"` on the `catch-exception-strategy` element

i.e. `<catch-exception-strategy logException="true">`

or else you can uncheck the "Log Exceptions" button from within studio's GUI.